# Htaccess Redirect from one subfolder to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking to do a .htaccess redirect for my author URL to a standard user profile URL

I'm looking to redirect
[https://domainname.com/author/{username}](https://domainname.com/author/%7Busername%7D) to [https://domainname.com/user/{username}](https://domainname.com/user/%7Busername%7D)

This is what I have at the moment but it doesn't seem to work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?author/(.*)$ /user/$1 [R,L]
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Full htaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/?$ /user/$1? [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 \,
RedirectMatch 403 \:
RedirectMatch 403 \;
RedirectMatch 403 \=
RedirectMatch 403 \[
RedirectMatch 403 \]
RedirectMatch 403 \^
RedirectMatch 403 \`
RedirectMatch 403 \{
RedirectMatch 403 \}
RedirectMatch 403 \~
RedirectMatch 403 \"
RedirectMatch 403 \$
RedirectMatch 403 \<
RedirectMatch 403 \>
RedirectMatch 403 \|
RedirectMatch 403 \.\.
RedirectMatch 403 \%0
RedirectMatch 403 \%A
RedirectMatch 403 \%B
RedirectMatch 403 \%C
RedirectMatch 403 \%D
RedirectMatch 403 \%E
RedirectMatch 403 \%F
RedirectMatch 403 \%22
RedirectMatch 403 \%27
RedirectMatch 403 \%28
RedirectMatch 403 \%29
RedirectMatch 403 \%3C
RedirectMatch 403 \%3E
RedirectMatch 403 \%3F
RedirectMatch 403 \%5B
RedirectMatch 403 \%5C
RedirectMatch 403 \%5D
RedirectMatch 403 \%7B
RedirectMatch 403 \%7C
RedirectMatch 403 \%7D
# COMMON PATTERNS
Redirectmatch 403 \_vpi
RedirectMatch 403 \.inc
Redirectmatch 403 xAou6
Redirectmatch 403 db\_name
Redirectmatch 403 select\(
Redirectmatch 403 convert\(
Redirectmatch 403 \/query\/
RedirectMatch 403 ImpEvData
Redirectmatch 403 \.XMLHTTP
Redirectmatch 403 proxydeny
RedirectMatch 403 function\.
Redirectmatch 403 remoteFile
Redirectmatch 403 servername
Redirectmatch 403 \&rptmode\=
Redirectmatch 403 sys\_cpanel
RedirectMatch 403 db\_connect
RedirectMatch 403 doeditconfig
RedirectMatch 403 check\_proxy
Redirectmatch 403 system\_user
Redirectmatch 403 \/\(null\)\/
Redirectmatch 403 clientrequest
Redirectmatch 403 option\_value
RedirectMatch 403 ref\.outcontrol
# SPECIFIC EXPLOITS
RedirectMatch 403 errors\.
RedirectMatch 403 config\.
RedirectMatch 403 include\.
RedirectMatch 403 display\.
RedirectMatch 403 register\.
Redirectmatch 403 password\.
RedirectMatch 403 maincore\.
RedirectMatch 403 authorize\.
Redirectmatch 403 macromates\.
RedirectMatch 403 head\_auth\.
RedirectMatch 403 submit\_links\.
RedirectMatch 403 change\_action\.
Redirectmatch 403 com\_facileforms\/
RedirectMatch 403 admin\_db\_utilities\.
RedirectMatch 403 admin\.webring\.docs\.
Redirectmatch 403 Table\/Latest\/index\.
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_ADVANCED_CHAR_STRING_FILTER_END
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-comments-post\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://domainname\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header set Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following .htaccess rules file, make sure to keep your .htaccess rules file along with user folder.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/?$ /user/$1? [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/?$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Your complete .htaccess rules file will be:

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/?$ /user/$1? [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 \,
RedirectMatch 403 \:
RedirectMatch 403 \;
RedirectMatch 403 \=
RedirectMatch 403 \[
RedirectMatch 403 \]
RedirectMatch 403 \^
RedirectMatch 403 \`
RedirectMatch 403 \{
RedirectMatch 403 \}
RedirectMatch 403 \~
RedirectMatch 403 \"
RedirectMatch 403 \$
RedirectMatch 403 \<
RedirectMatch 403 \>
RedirectMatch 403 \|
RedirectMatch 403 \.\.
RedirectMatch 403 \%0
RedirectMatch 403 \%A
RedirectMatch 403 \%B
RedirectMatch 403 \%C
RedirectMatch 403 \%D
RedirectMatch 403 \%E
RedirectMatch 403 \%F
RedirectMatch 403 \%22
RedirectMatch 403 \%27
RedirectMatch 403 \%28
RedirectMatch 403 \%29
RedirectMatch 403 \%3C
RedirectMatch 403 \%3E
RedirectMatch 403 \%3F
RedirectMatch 403 \%5B
RedirectMatch 403 \%5C
RedirectMatch 403 \%5D
RedirectMatch 403 \%7B
RedirectMatch 403 \%7C
RedirectMatch 403 \%7D
# COMMON PATTERNS
Redirectmatch 403 \_vpi
RedirectMatch 403 \.inc
Redirectmatch 403 xAou6
Redirectmatch 403 db\_name
Redirectmatch 403 select\(
Redirectmatch 403 convert\(
Redirectmatch 403 \/query\/
RedirectMatch 403 ImpEvData
Redirectmatch 403 \.XMLHTTP
Redirectmatch 403 proxydeny
RedirectMatch 403 function\.
Redirectmatch 403 remoteFile
Redirectmatch 403 servername
Redirectmatch 403 \&rptmode\=
Redirectmatch 403 sys\_cpanel
RedirectMatch 403 db\_connect
RedirectMatch 403 doeditconfig
RedirectMatch 403 check\_proxy
Redirectmatch 403 system\_user
Redirectmatch 403 \/\(null\)\/
Redirectmatch 403 clientrequest
Redirectmatch 403 option\_value
RedirectMatch 403 ref\.outcontrol
# SPECIFIC EXPLOITS
RedirectMatch 403 errors\.
RedirectMatch 403 config\.
RedirectMatch 403 include\.
RedirectMatch 403 display\.
RedirectMatch 403 register\.
Redirectmatch 403 password\.
RedirectMatch 403 maincore\.
RedirectMatch 403 authorize\.
Redirectmatch 403 macromates\.
RedirectMatch 403 head\_auth\.
RedirectMatch 403 submit\_links\.
RedirectMatch 403 change\_action\.
Redirectmatch 403 com\_facileforms\/
RedirectMatch 403 admin\_db\_utilities\.
RedirectMatch 403 admin\.webring\.docs\.
Redirectmatch 403 Table\/Latest\/index\.
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_ADVANCED_CHAR_STRING_FILTER_END
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-comments-post\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://domainname\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/?$ /user/$1? [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/?$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header set Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```